# got an Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; on lumen 5.6

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, lumen, laravel-query-builder

this is my code on my controller the get_time_age() is a function on the controller

```
//create query contents inner joint users
    $content = DB::table('contents')
                    ->join('users', 'contents.user_id', '=', 'users.iduser')
                    ->select('contents.idcontent', 'contents.user_id', 'users.nickname', 'contents.title', 'contents.content', 
                            'contents.createdate', 'contents.modifieddate', (DB::raw($this->get_time_ago(strtotime("contents.createdate")).' as timelapse')), 
                            'contents.delete')
                    ->where('contents.delete', 0)
                    ->orderBy('idcontent', 'desc')
                    ->get();
```

and i got an error 
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax

at Connection->select('select `contents`.`idcontent`, `contents`.`user_id`, `users`.`nickname`, `contents`.`title`, `contents`.`content`, `contents`.`createdate`, `contents`.`modifieddate`, 48 years ago as timelapse, `contents`.`delete` from `contents` inner join `users` on `contents`.`user_id` = `users`.`iduser` where `contents`.`delete` = ? order by `idcontent` desc', array(0), true)in Builder.php line 1963

Answer (score 3):

You have to wrap the string result of `get_time_ago()` in quotes:

```
DB::raw("'".$this->get_time_ago(strtotime("contents.createdate"))."' as timelapse")
```